# Reading a file .txt in C with blank spaces

Tags: c, fopen, fclose

I trying to open a simple txt file in C, like the image bellow.

[list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOa5O.png)

The input text :

```
Name    Sex Age Dad Mom 
Gabriel M   58  George  Claire          
Louise  F   44          
Pablo   M   19  David   Maria
```

My doubt is, how can i make to identify the blank spaces in the list and jump correctly to another lines.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *cfPtr;

    if ((cfPtr = fopen("clients.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        puts("The file can't be open");
    } else {
        char name[20];
        char sex[4];
        int age;
        char dad[20];
        char mom[20];
        char line[300];

    printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n","Name","Sex","Age","Dad","Mom");
    fgets(line,300,cfPtr);
    fscanf(cfPtr,"%10s%10s%d%12s%12s",name,sex,&age,dad,mom);

    while (!feof(cfPtr)) {
        printf("%-10s%-10s%d%12s%12s\n",name,sex,age,dad,mom);
        fscanf(cfPtr,"%19s%3s%d%12s%12s",name,sex,&age,dad,mom);
    }

        fclose(cfPtr);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

It works fine if I fill in all the spaces...

Comment: Post your sample input text here to add clarity to the post.  Link images are harder to use and links disappear.

Comment: "how can i make to identify the blank spaces" --> research using the return value from the function `fscanf()` instead of `feof(cfPtr)`. Who or what text suggested `while (!feof(cfPtr)) {`?

Comment: I edited with the input text.

Comment: The `while (!feof(cfPtr))` was an example from my teacher, i guess it wasnt a good one. I will try use the return value of fscanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> printf("%-10s%-10s%d%12s%12s\n",name,sex,age,dad,mom);
> fscanf(cfPtr,"%19s%3s%d%12s%12s",name,sex,&age,dad,mom);
> ```

Change the order to read first, print later.

Ideally the data in your file should be separated by comma, tab, or some other character. If data is in fixed columns, then read everything as text (including integers) then convert the integer to text later.

Also check the return value for `fscanf`, if the result is not 5 then some fields were missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{
    FILE *cfPtr = fopen("clients.txt", "r");
    if(cfPtr == NULL) 
    {
        puts("The file can't be open");
        return 0;
    }

    char name[11], sex[11], dad[11], mom[11], line[300];
    int age;

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), cfPtr); //skip the first line
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), cfPtr))
    {
        if(5 == sscanf(line, "%10s%10s%10d%10s%10s", name, sex, &age, dad, mom))
            printf("%s, %s, %d, %s, %s\n", name, sex, age, dad, mom);
    }

    fclose(cfPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit, changed `sscan` format to read integer directly, changed buffer allocation to 11 which is all that's needed.

Comment: @Why use `%10s` with `char name[20]`?

Comment: @chux, I changed the allocation to 11 to make you happy.